# jquery mouseenter / mouseleave results in flickering featherlight lightbox

Tags: jquery

Tried a few different things (like changing the lightbox div to pointer-events:none) but nothing seems to help. Are there any ways to keep the lightbox open until the user moves off the trigger element?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#theboxa').mouseenter(function () {
        $.featherlight('#boxa', {});
    });

    $('#theboxa').mouseleave(function () {
      $.featherlight.close();
    });
});
```

I believe the flickering is caused by the pointer automatically moving to the lightbox (#boxa) but dont know how to prevent this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in order for us to reproduce your issue as currently we simply cannot.

Comment: you can see other instances of this issue here >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570910/jquery-mouseover-mouseout-div-is-flickering ... HTH

Comment: dw fixed it myself